# Walk through QTableView rows using tab key

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I have a `QTableView` and i wanted the user to be able to select a whole row rather than individual cell. So i changed the selection behavior as shown below.

`table->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows)`

But now when the tab key is clicked it still walks through individual cells rather than whole row. I want the user to be able to walk through each row rather individual cells.

Comment: What do you mean by "when the tab is clicked"? Do you mean the tab key? Also note that there are both selected and focused ("current") items, if you set `SelectRows` behaviour, the selection will be the full row, but the focus will still be on cell level, is that what you are seeing?

Comment: @Karsten Koop Yes i meant tab key in the keyboard. Also if a user clicks on any part of a row, the whole row must be highlighted/selected. I don't want QTableView to consider individual cells, but a row should be considered as a single item.

Comment: So the selection (blue highlighting) is still on cell level after you set `SelectRows`? This is strange, maybe there is some other reason why this does not get set or gets resetted. At which point do you call `setSelectionBehaviour`? Right after creating the view?

Comment: @KarstenKoop When a cell is clicked, the whole row gets highlighted. But problem is that tab key must be pressed n times(n is the column number) to get to the next row.

Comment: Ah, I see. The tab key is usually used to open the next cell for editing, and editing has to be always on cell level. I assume your TabView is not editable, so you don't want this. You could either tell the user to use the arrow keys, or override the `keyPressEvent` of the view and handle the tab yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must inherit from `QTableView` class and override `keyPressEvent()`. For example:

```
#include <QTableView>
#include <QKeyEvent>

class CustomView : public QTableView
{
    Q_OBJECT

    // QWidget interface
protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) {
        switch(event->key()) {
        case Qt::Key_Tab: {
            if(currentIndex().row() != model()->rowCount())
                selectRow(currentIndex().row() + 1);
            break;
        }
        default: QTableView::keyPressEvent(event);
        }
    }

public:
    explicit CustomView(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~CustomView(){}

signals:

public slots:

};
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to subclassing `QTableView`, you can install an event filter on it. For example, here I'm using the MainWindow of my program to filter events on a table view, which is one of the window's child widgets:

In mainwindow.h:

```
class MainWindow: public QMainWindow {
private:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event) override;
}
```

In mainwindow.cpp:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    if (watched == ui->tableView &&
        event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress &&
        static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event)->key() == Qt::Key_Tab)
    {
        //Handle the tab press here
        return true;  //return true to skip further event handling
    }

    //If the event was not a tab press on the tableView, let any other handlers do their thing:
    return false;
}
```

Then, in `MainWindow::MainWindow()` (or wherever) you install the event filter like this:

```
ui->tableView->installEventFilter(this);
```